# Unable to login to high available keycloak cluster

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

Im using bitnami helm chart for keycloak.  and trying to achieve High availability with 3 keycloak replics, using DNS ping.

```
Chart version: 5.2.8
Image version: 15.1.1-debian-10-r10
Helm repo: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami -> bitnami/keycloak
```

The modified parameters of values.yaml file is as follows:

```
global:
  image:
    registry: docker.io
    repository: bitnami/keycloak
    tag: 15.1.1-debian-10-r10
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    pullSecrets: []
    debug: true

proxyAddressForwarding: true

serviceDiscovery:
  enabled: true
  protocol: dns.DNS_PING
  properties:
    - dns_query=keycloak.identity.svc.cluster.local  
  transportStack: tcp

cache:
  ownersCount: 3
  authOwnersCount: 3

replicaCount: 3

ingress:
  enabled: true
  hostname: my-keycloak.keycloak.example.com
  apiVersion: ""
  ingressClassName: "nginx"
  path: /
  pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  annotations: {}
  tls: false
  extraHosts: []
  extraTls: []
  secrets: []
  existingSecret: ""
  servicePort: http
```

When login to the keycloak UI, after entering the username and password , the login does not happen, it redirects the back to login page.

From the pod logs I see following error:

```
0:07:05,251 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-1) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=security-admin-console, userId=null, ipAddress=10.244.5.46, error=invalid_code, grant_type=authorization_code, code_id=157e0483-67fa-4ea4-a964-387f3884cbc9, client_auth_method=client-secret
```

When I checked about this error in forums, As per some suggestions to set proxyAddressForwarding to true, but with this as well, issue remains same.

Apart from this I have tried some other version of the helm chart , but with that the UI itself does not load correctly with page not found errors.

### Update

I get the above error i.e, `CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR` in logs when I use the headless service with ingress. But if I use the service of type ClusterIP with ingress , the error is as follows:

```
06:43:37,587 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-6) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=10.122.0.26, error=expired_code, restart_after_timeout=true, authSessionParentId=453870cd-5580-495d-8f03-f73498cd3ace, authSessionTabId=1d17vpIoysE
```

Another additional information I would like to post is , I see following INFO in all the keycloak pod logs at the startup.

```
05:27:10,437 INFO  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) my-keycloak-0: no members discovered after 3006 ms: creating cluster as coordinator
```

This sounds like the 3 members have not combined and not formed a keycloak cluster.

Comment: Just to make it more clear to understand the situation, can you confirm if the login form that you submit is being sent to the same node that originally served you the form?

Comment: Yes. It is because I see the error in all 3 pod logs.

Comment: what happens if you run keycloak with only one replica/pod

Comment: It works fine, i.e, Im able to login without any issues.

Answer (score 4):

One common scenario that may lead to such a situation is when the node that issued the access code is not the one who has received the *code to token* request. So the client gets the access code from node 1 but the second request reaches node 2 and the value is not yet in this node's cache. The safest approach to prevent such scenario is to setup a session sticky load balancer.

I suggest you to try setting the `service.spec.sessionAffinity` to `ClientIP`. Its default value is `None`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but unfortunately I'm still getting same error with this change as well. 
And I have updated my questions with few more observations that I have noticed.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the error

> expired_code

might indicate a mismatch in timekeeping between the server and the client